# How to change comma to dot in column with vba?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to change "," to "." in column B.

I tried to change Range column (B:B), but it doesn't work.

```
Sub changecommatodot()    
Dim commatodot As String    
commatodot = Replace(Range("B:B"), ",", ".")      
Range("B:B") = "'" & commatodot    
End sub
```

I expect to have values in column B as 2.3 instead of 2,3.

Answer (score 0):

This task can be easily recorded with the macro recorder.

The result code looks like this:

```
Sub Makro1()
    Columns("B:B").select
    selection.Replace What:=",", Replacement:=".", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
End Sub
```

You can clean the code to:

```
Sub changecommatodot()
    sheets("Sheet1").Columns("B:B").Replace What:=",", Replacement:="."
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, but my code is more simplest, it works for one cell e.g B1 - why it doesn't for B:B ?

Comment: the replace function expects a string as a first argument. You are passing in a column, which is a complex object.

Comment: If you like, you could loop through the column and apply the replace function to each cell

Comment: I cleaned the code to the relevant part. Now it is very simple an works very fast.

Comment: `sheets("Sheet1").Columns("B:B").Replace What:=",", Replacement:="."` is the code you need. Just change the name of "Sheet1" to your sheet name and you are ready to go

Comment: No errors, but no effects, the comma is not replaced. I pasted the code to Sheet object and change the sheet name.

Comment: ok, I see, but e.g 1,2 change to date format 01 Feb. insted of 1.2

Comment: @czaruska It is also possible that your PC recognizes "," as decimal places for numbers and Excel uses those settings by default. If you wish to use "." as decimal places go to: Control Panel > Clock and Region > Region > Additional Settings, and there you will find settings for Numbers, Currency, Time and Date. You are interested in "Numbers" and the first field, called "Decimal symbol". If you change it to a "." then you will have numbers in the whole computer in "1.2" format.